# Measuring system clock (time) of a remote server

Tags: time, time-synchronization

What are the network protocols that can be used to measure the system clock (time) of a remote server? So far I have:

- Query with NTP
- [TCP Timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_timestamps)
- HTTP headers

Are there any other?

Answer (score 1):

There's always the [Daytime Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol)

From the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc867):

```
A useful debugging and measurement tool is a daytime service.  A daytime
service simply sends a the current date and time as a character string
without regard to the input.

TCP Based Daytime Service

One daytime service is defined as a connection based application on
TCP.  A server listens for TCP connections on TCP port 13.  Once a
connection is established the current date and time is sent out the
connection as a ascii character string (and any data received is
thrown away).  The service closes the connection after sending the
quote.

UDP Based Daytime Service

Another daytime service service is defined as a datagram based
application on UDP.  A server listens for UDP datagrams on UDP port
13.  When a datagram is received, an answering datagram is sent
containing the current date and time as a ASCII character string (the
data in the received datagram is ignored).
```